# Angular Directive - replace default img tag with new directive possible?

Tags: angularjs

We have a legacy application that uses a WYSIWYG editor that creates img tags with just an ID number as the src, then that ID number in the src is later replaced with the actual path to the image.  For an AngularJS 1.3 re-write of the legacy app I need to create a directive that does the same sort of thing, such that our directive would read the src and replace the src with the new path.  The original tag output by the editor plugin would be something like this:

```
<img src="70"></img>
```

Our directive would read the src on this img tag, look up the path with a database call, then replace that original img tag with something like this:

```
<img src="images/logo.jpg"></img>
```

Could I use something like this code below?  How would I finish this code?  I read that the 'replace' functionality of directives is deprecated in Angular 1.3.  Will this prevent us from using this approach?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('img', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
        var imageId = attrs.src;
        $http.get('getImagePath/' + imageId).then(function() {
        // replace image tag with img src set to new path

        }
        }
    };

}]);
```

Any suggestions or directions greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no special need for a special directive here.

Angular is so great that it allows you to use `ng-src`.

> What Is `ng-src`?

`ng-src` is the directive that you are looking for, it evaluates expressions or bindings, it is smart, and you can link it to a function on your controller that will do the logic.

an example would be:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function(){

$scope.turnIDtoThisLink = function(id){

   $http.get( ....... ).success(function(data){
    var img = data.url //example.
   }); // fill accordingly.
    return img;
}
});
```

and on the html:

```
<img ng-src="{{turnIDtoThisLinkn(id)}}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think one issue is that I was told that the html will already be created with a static normal image tag like this: <img src="70"></img>.  How would we be able to convert that to the directive syntax of: <img ng-src="{{turnIDtoThisLinkn(70)}}"/> ?

Comment: since AngularJS 1.3 introduced, it now silently ignores unevaluated expressions. Besides who ever told you that meant to ng-src="{{binding}}" will try to do what you written. please give it a shot, you wont be sorry :)

Comment: Also you can look at this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/wktwL/5/ Try to play around it. you could also add some logic when it comes to odd cases.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think I explained my original situation very well.  I am not able to type in 'ng-src' the html file, the html is automatically generated for us by an editor plug-in running on the client and it outputs img tags like this: <img src="70"></img>.

Comment: Well in that case it sounds like you should use DOM manipulation, something like jQuery might come handy. But if I were you I would have rewrite the plug-in to be Angulared the thing about Angular is that it provides both performance and scaleability, if that is impossible I would have gone with some unorthodox method that receives the complete the string and rewrites it in Angular.

Comment: Could be also a way to do this with $compile function